# Ruby TCPSocket read until custom terminator character

Tags: ruby, sockets, string-concatenation, terminator

Here is my code to listen client TCP socket:

```
def initialize
    @msg = ''
    @messages = Queue.new
    @socket = TCPSocket.open('127.0.0.1', 2000)
    Thread.new do
        loop do
            ch = @socket.recv(1)
            if ch == "\n"
                puts @msg unless @msg.blank?
                @msg = ''
            else
                @msg += ch
            end
        end
    end
end
```

What I don't like is byte-by-byte string concatenation. It should be not memory-efficient.

The `read` method of socket reads until newline. Could the socket read until some custom terminator character, for example `0x00` ?

If not, then which memory-efficient string appenging do you know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`IO#gets`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-gets) with a custom separator:

```
# tcp_test.rb
require 'socket'

TCPSocket.open('127.0.0.1', 2000) do |socket|
  puts socket.gets("\0").chomp("\0") # chomp removes the separator
end
```

Test server using [Netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat):

```
$ echo -ne "foo\0bar" | nc -l 2000
```

Output:

```
$ ruby tcp_test.rb
foo
```

You could even set the *input record separator* to `"\0"`:

```
$/ = "\0"
puts socket.gets.chomp
```

Comment: Please explain `$/ = "\0"`

Comment: `$/` is a [global variable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/globals_rdoc.html) and the default input record separator used by `gets`, `chomp` and others. Its default value is `"\n"`